# What is the best way to create a custom federated image dataset for TFF in SQLite format?

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I went through the source for the CIFAR-100 inbuilt dataset and decided to create a compatible version for the FairFace dataset in order to be able to leverage the other built-in functions without many modifications everywhere once I convert FairFace into a structure very similar to CIFAR-100.

I did search around but was unable to find how the CIFAR-100 SQLite database was created - specifically how the images were converted into BLOB for storage. After a bit of trial and error, I tried doing it this way:

```py
sample = getDatabyIndex(train_labels, index)
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
  'image' : bytes_feature(sample[0].tobytes()),
  'label' : int64_feature(sample[1])
}))
example = example.SerializeToString()
cur.execute("insert into examples('split_name','client_id','serialized_example_proto') values(?,?,?)", ('train', i, sqlite3.Binary(example)))
```

Executing this for each sample in the train data and similarly for test data. I am able to load it using this decoding method:

```py
def parse_proto(tensor_proto):
  parse_spec = {
    'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.string),
    'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64),
  }
  decoded_example = tf.io.parse_example(tensor_proto, parse_spec)
  return collections.OrderedDict(
            image=tf.reshape(tf.io.decode_raw(decoded_example['image'], tf.uint8), (224,224,3)),
            label=decoded_example['label'])
```

What I noticed, however, is that the final sqlite.lzma compressed archive is 6.4 GB in size whereas the source archive for the dataset was 555 MB. I am guessing that due to the way I am storing the images, compression is not working as well as it could if they were stored in a more compatible manner. I see from the CIFAR-100 code that the images are loaded directly as FixedLenFeatures of shape (32,32,3) which means that they were stored as such but I have been unable to find a way to store my images as such. The only method that worked for me was the bytes_feature route.

What would be the best/recommended way to go about this?

Comment: Do I follow the question correctly: the size of the SQLite database _before_ compression is 555 MiB and after compression is 6.5 GiB (compression made the file _much_ larger)? Could the question be expanded to include how LZMA compression is applied to the SQLite database file?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about LZMA compression is being applied its hard to answer about the size increase.

To directly use the same `tf.io.FixedLenFeature` as the CIFAR-100 dataset from [`tff.simulation.datasets.cifar100.load_data`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/simulation/datasets/cifar100/load_data) the `tf.train.Example` needs to be constructed using`int64_feature()` for the `'image'` key instead of bytes. This may require casting `sample[0]` to a different dtype (assuming it is a `np.ndarray`).

During decoding:

1. First parse as an `(N, M, 3)` tensor with int64. From [tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/datasets/cifar100.py#L31](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1868b9b1af37efd377d0f73ce143df431cfde82e/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/datasets/cifar100.py#L31):

   ```py
   'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature(shape=(32, 32, 3), dtype=tf.int64),
   ```
2. Cast to `tf.unit8`. From [tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/datasets/cifar100.py#L37](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/1868b9b1af37efd377d0f73ce143df431cfde82e/tensorflow_federated/python/simulation/datasets/cifar100.py#L37):

   ```py
   image=tf.cast(parsed_features['image'], tf.uint8),
   ```

NOTE: Because of varint encoding used in protocol buffers (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints), using int64 isn't expected to add significant overhead for the serialized representation (at least less than 4x).